What do these numbers represent in the equation to calculate machining power (refer below)?
The equation here has numbers 75, 1.36 and 60. Out of which 60 is understood, it convers minutes to seconds. What do we mean by 75 and 1.36?


please add the source of the document to your post ... do not write in a comment
